# What is the correct name for Typescript "Anonymous" type definitions?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking at this line of code `options?: { name?: string, async?: boolean }`.  What is the correct term for the type `{ name?: string, async?: boolean }`?  It looks like an "Anonymous class" definition in Java, but I'm guessing it's called something else ...

Comment: Do you want the name the TypeScript's AST parser uses for that syntax?

Comment: @lilezek I would like to know what name is used in the parser. Did you find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Typescript Language Specification, these are called [Object Type Literals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.8.3):

> An object type literal defines an object type by specifying the set of
>   members that are statically considered to be present in instances of
>   the type. Object type literals can be given names using interface
>   declarations but are otherwise anonymous.
>
> *ObjectType:*
>      `{` *TypeBody<sub>opt</sub>* `}`
>
> *TypeBody:*
>      *TypeMemberList* `;`*<sub>opt</sub>*
>      *TypeMemberList* `,`*<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> *TypeMemberList:*
>      *TypeMember*
>      *TypeMemberList* `;` *TypeMember*
>      *TypeMemberList* `,` *TypeMember*
>
> *TypeMember:*
>      *PropertySignature*
>      *CallSignature*
>      *ConstructSignature*
>      *IndexSignature*
>      *MethodSignature*

Comment: Does this not only apply to it’s usage with an object? I would think the last sentence implies the correct term is “anonymous”: `Object type literals can be given names using interface declarations but are otherwise anonymous.`

Comment: @RickLove Anonymous here refers to the fact that an `ObjectType` has no name, unless it's declared within an interface. I'm not sure what you mean with "does this not only apply to it’s usage with an object?"; what is an object in your question?

Comment: I mean that it is not only an object type literal that can be anonymous, so I don’t think this is answering about the anonymous aspect of the question, but only as it applies to an object (this is an anonymous object type literal). For example, it is possible to also have an anonymous array type, anonymous union type, anonymous etc type (looking below the quoted section in the referenced document.)

Comment: In fact here is the answer, in the same document: Type queries are useful for capturing *anonymous types* that are generated by various constructs such as object literals, function declarations, and namespace declarations. I give you credit for finding the correct document, but I would request you update to indicate this reference for future visitors.

Comment: @RickLove the question isn't about _anonymous types_, it's about what `{ name?: string, async?: boolean }` is called. When it's an array, it's called an _Array Type Literal_. An _anonymous type_ exists when you don't define a type for a given variable/object/array/whatever and it is instead deduced by the compiler.

Comment: A _type query_ in TypeScript is done by using the `typeof` keyword.

Comment: The question was about what anonymous types are called, not limiting it to the scope of object type literals. The documentation mentions the phrase “anonymous types” and “type literals can be given names but are otherwise anonymous” which indicates that anonymous is the part of the name that refers to a type definition not having a name, which is the focus of the OP.

Comment: Also, an object type literal may or may not have a name (I.e. it may or may not be anonymous as the OP is asking about.) For example, if an interface is used to define the type, it is still an object type literal, but the type has a name.

Comment: @RickLove The question reads: "What is the correct term for the type `{ name?: string, async?: boolean }`?". I think my answer is satisfactory to this question. If you don't believe so then please post your own answer or update it accordingly. Ole has accepted my answer, so it seems to satisfy his curiousity :-).

Answer (score -2):

*Anonymous Type* is correct:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.8.10

> Type queries are useful for capturing *anonymous types* that are generated by various constructs such as object literals, function declarations, and namespace declarations.

——-

Original Answer:

I’m not sure, but here are some things I’ve called it:

- Unnamed Type
- Adhoc Type
- Anonymous Type

---

A note:

Typescript uses duck typing, so it is possible to use alternate type description that have matching type members interchangeably.

Another words: an object that quacks like a duck can be called a duck, no matter what type it was originally declared as (or whether it had an Named type declaration or only an adhoc one like your example).

So if you have a type:

`type Options = {name?:string, async?: boolean};`

The object in the question is of the same type (as far as the type system is concerned), even though it was never declared to have this type.

However, in tooltips, the IDE will usually only show the declared type.

Comment: Inferred types are not the same as explicit types that aren't assigned to a name.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are correct, I removed that suggestion from my answer and remained only with the note about duck typing.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question though :-).

Comment: @DavidWalschots so why did you put it back? It's not relevant to the OP's question, and if people want to see what was previously there they can view the history.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is relevant because duck-typing works differently than strong-typing as the OP mentioned he is familiar with Java.

Comment: @RickLove but that's *still not what they asked*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe an edit shouldn't change the author's intent. Whether we believe it's the right or wrong answer doesn't matter :-). If we have a better answer, we should provide our own.